# Copy file from windows to linux without Modifying file timestamp using SAS

Tags: linux, sas, sas-macro, pull, smb

I want to copy excel file file from windows to Linux system and need to capture last modified date of the file.

We cant take take last modified date of the file from windows.

Since i am using below code to copy file from Windows to Linux, Code is able to transfer file to Linux system however once after running the code the timestamp of the file is changing. Is there any way to copy file from windows to linux without modifying file timestamp. Please help.

```
%smb_init(username=**MYID**, password=%str(**password**), domain=**aa.aaa.com**);

%smb_load();
%smb_pull(windows=//files/Load/Test/Folder1/PIC Alerts/ABC Alerts.xlsx,
linux=/sasdata/test_files/folder2/ABC_Alerts.xlsx);
```

Comment: How is `%smb_pull` set up? Is it using x commands?

Comment: Yeah...No need to set up %smb _pull... Same for %smb_push aswell.... Any idea how can i transfer file without modifying timestamp? Appreciate your comment...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to copy files while preserving attributes, [enable X commands in SAS](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=webeditorag&docsetTarget=p0awzsi827nb5qn100slqvn31q61.htm&docsetVersion=3.8&locale=en) and let the OS handle copying files. After enabling it, it's as simple as using a built-in Linux file copying command like [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

For example, this will copy data, attributes, and timestamps:

`rsync -av //source/mydata.xlsx /dest/mydata.xlsx`

Once you confirm it works as expected, you can build it into your SAS program and pass it to Linux:

`x 'rsync -av //source/mydata.xlsx /dest/mydata.xlsx';`

The automatic macro variable `&sysrc` will tell you if it was successful. A value of 0 means success. Non-zero means failure.

Comment: Hi...This will not work because this is windows code to run in windows system...I am trying same using SAS...